# 2d cross section of a pde solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am solving a PDE with position, x and time, t variables numerically. After solving, mathematica returns a solution in the form of a interpolating function[x,t] which  can plot using Plot3D. Now, I want to look at specific time slices of the solution to see dependence on x at each time.

How can I get these cross sections?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please share some code?

Comment: See the docs for `NDSolve` > Scope > Partial Differential Equations and search for the ListAnimate example for an example of doing this for f(t, x, y). It's the same idea for f(t, x), but use `Plot[]` instead of `Plot3D[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try for `t=t1` `Plot[function[x,t1],{x,x1,x2(*your xrange*)}]`

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this before. Turns out I had defined the PDE in a bad way. I fixed that and now this works:)